# Fading out randomly generated pixels with jQuery/Babel and canvas

Tags: html, babeljs

I'm working on a project called BitDay (bitday.me). One of our users mentioned it'd be cool to have a northern lights effect when they clicked and dragged on the night sky.

JSFiddle progress - https://jsfiddle.net/ue98wpzg/1/

```js
let width, height;
let pixels = [];
let coloredPixels = [];
let colors = ['#196491', '#023053', '#27AAD4', '#1DCD8C', '#37897e', '#2ea187', '#1f3f64', '#0cc082', '#06da7a', '#0ee481', '#414e76', '#06de58'];
let currentPixel = 0;
const mousePosition = { x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/2 };

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const drawGrid = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
  for (var i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    pixels[i][10] = 0;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0, l = coloredPixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    var pix = Math.floor(coloredPixels[i].y/10)*(Math.floor(width/10)+1) + Math.floor(coloredPixels[i].x/10);
    if (pixels[pix]) {
      pixels[pix][4] = coloredPixels[i].color;
      pixels[pix][5] = coloredPixels[i].alpha;
    }
    
    if (coloredPixels[i].alpha > 0) coloredPixels[i].alpha -= 0.08;
    if (coloredPixels[i].alpha < 0) coloredPixels[i].alpha = 0;
    coloredPixels[i].x += coloredPixels[i].vx;
    coloredPixels[i].y += coloredPixels[i].vy;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i++) {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(pixels[i][0], pixels[i][1], pixels[i][2], pixels[i][3]);
    ctx.globalAlpha = pixels[i][5];
    ctx.fillStyle = pixels[i][4];
    ctx.fillRect(pixels[i][0], pixels[i][1], pixels[i][2], pixels[i][3]);
  }
}

const resize = () => {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  pixels = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < height/2; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width/10; x++) {
      pixels.push([x*8, y*8, 8, 8, '#000']);
    }
  }
}

const draw = () => {
  launchPixel();
  launchPixel();
  drawGrid();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

const initColoredPixels = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    coloredPixels.push({
      x: width/10,
      y: height/20,
      alpha: 1,
      color: colors[i%15],
      vx: -2 + Math.random()*10,
      vy: -25 + Math.random()*20
    })
  }
}

const launchPixel = () => {
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].x = mousePosition.x*1.2;
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].y = mousePosition.y*1.2;
  coloredPixels[currentPixel].alpha = 1;
  
  currentPixel++;
  if (currentPixel > 999) currentPixel = 0;
}

resize();
initColoredPixels();
draw();

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mousePosition.x = e.pageX;
  mousePosition.y = e.pageY;
})

const touchMove = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  mousePosition.x = e.touches[0].pageX;
  mousePosition.y = e.touches[0].pageY;
}

document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
```

```css
body {
  background: #101010;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100" id="canvas" style="opacity: 1"></canvas>
```

Problem 1 - Pixels get stuck and don't disappear. Ideally we'd want them to linger until mouseup and then slowly fade up and disappear.

Problem 2 - Need to make it so they only appear when clicked/tapped and dragged.

Problem 3 - Can't seem to get this to fill 100% width of screen.

I'm pretty stuck with all 3 of these, spent ages trying to get the formula right but to no avail. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Do you have it git reporsitory? if yes, then i could help you

Comment: Yes I can create one for you later on :)

Comment: Here's the GitHub repo - https://github.com/DannyCare/pixel-northern-lights